# Background image scaling changes after uploading website

Tags: css, image, background

I'm trying to scale a background image to the full size of the browserwindow. 
When testing in the browser, I get the result I want, even when scaling the browserwindow.

But when I upload my website, I get an another result on my iPhone. 
The background image is very zoomed in...
Don't have a clue where to check this fault..

This is the website: samverdyck.be/felia

```
#home{
background: url(../img/feliahome.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Comment: http://viewportsizes.com/ + http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Try to use `contain` instead of `cover` because this is what `cover` does `Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. **Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area**` -> appears as if its zoomed.

Comment: when using contain the image appears in his actual with and heigth, and doesn't cover the whole background space...

Comment: on my iphone and tablet it doesn't show up anymore, I just get a blank area

Comment: Found the problem, removed the "fixed" value and it's working fine on every device. :-)